# Creating objects with data from file

Tags: java, file, io, hashmap

I’ve got a text file with data for my application and I want to create objects with that data. Every line in the text file is one object in format: `<name> <posX> <posY> <posY> <velX> <velY> <velZ> <mass> <radius>`.
`line` is a `String` with one line from that file. To read the data I split the `string` on whitespace. Then I get the first element to the variable `name`.

```
String[] args = line.split("\\s+");
String name = args[0];
```

Then I want to take next parameters from the line. I could surely do it like this:

```
double posX = Double.parseDouble(args[1]);
double posY = Double.parseDouble(args[2]);
double posZ = Double.parseDouble(args[3]);
double velX = Double.parseDouble(args[4]);
double velY = Double.parseDouble(args[5]);
double velZ = Double.parseDouble(args[6]);
double mass = Double.parseDouble(args[7]);
double radius = Double.parseDouble(args[8]);
```

However, it doesn’t look great. I have thought about doing it like that:

```
Map<String, Double> params = new HashMap<>();
String[] keys = {"posX", "posY", "posZ", "velX", "velY", "velZ", "mass", "radius"};
int i = 1;
for (String key : keys) {
      params.put(key, Double.parseDouble(args[i]));
      i++;
}
```

Now I’m not sure if it’s the best possible approach to my problem. Do you know any better way to do it?

Comment: [Serialization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html).

Comment: Write a constructor that takes a single string as a parameter.  You only have to write the string-parsing code once.  After that, `MyClass mine = new MyClass(myString)` will do all the parsing for you.

Comment: Your first way looks absolutely fine to me.

Comment: Shouldn't this be on code review? http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It ultimately comes to what you want to do with the data.

If you want to create an instance of a class that stores the data for each entry in the file, the current parsing is probably fine. You can do it with key-value pairs like a hash map (or dictionary, in other languages), but it is slower performance-wise than attributes when you are actually using the objects.

There is nothing wrong with having a lot of lines in a parsing operation, since that is considered boilerplate code anyway (and shouldn't need to be seen again once you define the file formats). Ultimately your way with a loop and a hash map compiles down to roughly the same number of actual instructions executed on your machine, so why put performance over aesthetics for something like this?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `new class of Java`, in this case `Example`, in which you will have a constructor (with the same name) like this:

```
public class Example{

double posX, posY, posZ,velX,velY,velZ,mass,radius;
String name;

   public Example(String line){

   String[] args = line.split("\\s+");

   name = args[0];
   posX = Double.parseDouble(args[1]);
   posY = Double.parseDouble(args[2]);
   posZ = Double.parseDouble(args[3]);
   velX = Double.parseDouble(args[4]);
   velY = Double.parseDouble(args[5]);
   velZ = Double.parseDouble(args[6]);
   mass = Double.parseDouble(args[7]);
   radius = Double.parseDouble(args[8]);
   }
```

In this class you can have all `GET` and `SET` methods for recover information from the object or modify it, respectively. You will have to make each `GET` and `SET` method for each variable that you use on your object. For example, if you want to make GET and SET methods for the variable `name` you have to do like this:

```
public void setName (String n) {
   this.name = n;
} 

public String getName (){
  return name;
}
```

And the same for all the variables that you have in your object.

Then, from your `Main class of Java` you can create a new object like this:

```
Example object = new Example(string);
```

where `string` it's the string that you want to use to create the object.

It will makes your code more clearly.

I expect it will be useful for you.